# QGIS 3 embedded forms - zoom or pan to child features

Tags: qgis-3, zoom, relates, forms

I have two tables and a relation defined on them via an 'in-between-table' (many-to-many relationship) like this:

[image]

This gives me nice embedded forms like shown below:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is to **zoom or pan to a child feature** listed in the embedded form.

In the form view I tried:

[image]

- (A) Activating zoom or pan to selected feature **seems to have no effect** in embedded forms, just in "normal" form view attribute table
- (B) The button 'Zoom to child features' is **allways greyed out** and sometimes vanishes (even when child features exist) an never returns.

The attribute tables table view has a context menu with entries like 'Zoom/Pan to Feature', thus it would be obvious to try the same in the table view in embedded forms, but herein the context menu looks slightly different (menu cut at top and bottom):

[image]

This is all in all especially weird, when the parent table has no geometry and there is no chance to zoom or pan to child features of a distinct parent feature.

Can someone reproduce this and / or tell me how to achieve this 'zoom to child feature'?

Comment: Too late I think but for others, look at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34477